# Disable Links on Page Load, Enable Links after 5 Seconds - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, timer

I want to disable every single `<a href=""></a>` on the page via javascript as soon as the page loads.

I then want to wait 5 seconds, and enable every `<a href=""></a>`.

I have tried a few methods without success (searching,googling for the past 30 minutes with nothing that is working).

Can anyone figure out how to do this with javascript?

Answer (score 0):

```
// Function that does nothing, but prevents default event handler
function disableLink(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
};

window.onload = function() {
    // Bind above event handler to all anchors
    var els = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
    [].forEach.call(els, function(el, i) {
        el.addEventListener("click", disableLink);
    });
    // Remove it in 5 seconds
    setTimeout(function() {
        var els = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
        [].forEach.call(els, function(el, i) {
            el.removeEventListener("click", disableLink);
        });
    }, 5000);
};
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/qL1njoqx/4/)

Comment: i cannot get this to work, even with a basic fresh html file... im simply doing the script and a `<a href="">link</a>` and it doesn't work?

Comment: I had the arguments to the `forEach` call back in the wrong order. And in the jsfiddle, you need to use the No Wrap option. If you use the OnLoad option, the code isrun in the `window.onload` handler, so adding a new `window.onload` handler doesn't do anything because the event has already taken place.